# regex replace leading spaces in text line

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string:

```
"    Some text here\n   Some new line text here"
```

I need to get from it:

```
"----Some text here\n---Some new line text here"
```

So that each space in the beginning of the line (string or line break symbol) would be replaces with say dash.

Not sure how to implement it the simplest way.

Comment: Your questions solved your problem. You want to replace one space with one dash. Regex maps quite well from natural language, as the answer demonstrates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following:

```
> "    Some text here\n   Some new line text here".replace(/^\s+/gm, '----')
"----Some text here\m----Some new line text here"
```

or:

```
"    Some text here\n   Some new line text here".replace(/^\s+/gm, function(spaces) { return spaces.replace(/./g, '-'); } )
"----Some text here\m----Some new line text here"
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes the second option works, not sure about first. I wonder if it is the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to match each leading pattern individually using a lookbehind, but this is an ECMAScript 2018+ only compatible solution.

Lookbehind adoption can be [tracked here](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/), see *RegExp Lookbehind Assertions*. 
Right now, they are supported by Chrome, Edge, Opera including Opera Mobile, Samsung Internet, and Node.js. [Firefox is adding "support for the dotAll flag, lookbehind references, named captures, and Unicode escape sequences"](https://9to5linux.com/mozilla-firefox-78-enters-beta-with-updated-minimal-linux-system-requirements) to the SpiderMonkey RegExp engine on June 30, 2020.

Solution for the current scenario:

```
.replace(/(?<=^\s*)\s/gm, '-')
```

Here, `/(?<=^\s*)\s/gm` matches any whitespace char (`\s`) that is immediately preceded with any 0+ whitespace chars at the start of the line (see the `(?<=^\s*)` positive lookbehind). See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/75P2zt/1).

**NOTE**: since `\s` matches line break chars, all empty lines will be replaced with a hyphen, too. If empty lines must be preserved use `[^\S\n\v\f\r\u2028\u2029` instead of `\s`:

```
.replace(/(?<=^[^\S\n\v\f\r\u2028\u2029]*)[^\S\n\v\f\r\u2028\u2029]/gm, '-')
```

where `[^\S\n\v\f\r\u2028\u2029]` matches any whitespace char other than linefeed, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, line and paragraph separators. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/75P2zt/2).

JS demo:

```js
// Any whitespace chars
console.log("    Some text here\n\n   Some new line text here"
     .replace(/(?<=^\s*)\s/gm, '-'))

// Only horizontal whitespace
console.log("    Some text here\n\n   Some new line text here"
     .replace(/(?<=^[^\S\n\v\f\r\u2028\u2029]*)[^\S\n\v\f\r\u2028\u2029]/gm, '-'))
```

Comment: No need downvoting correct answers, see [working demo on Node.js](https://tio.run/##tY/LCsJADEX3fkXoph1RK658In6Bi7pzFEob28o0KTNjq/58HQXxAS7NIoscLvfkGNexSXRR2T5xim2bMBlWOFCcBd4mR9CY4RlSLHnqiVnng4ObiEsEi2cLOWqUJOl5JGxAFfRGvc49AQONlYoTDMJgOV/spekKacKs7IHf94X47FhRCsQNWOdi0KH0WykMYU3qAjnr4spkYwVNXlg0lev4h/B2LyOXq@VBankaDUfjx57suuIner3Xtjc).

Comment: Not the first time I see a downvote answering an older question. It works and it is well explained ++